# Is "The top gets higher, the more that I climb" correct?

Tags: word-order, comparative-constructions

> The top gets higher, the more that I climb.

It's from a [song](http://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/lilwayne/droptheworld.html).

Shouldn't it be "the higher the top gets, the more I climb"?

Comment: What is wrong in the first place?

Comment: Shouldn't it be "the higher the top gets, the more I climb"?

Comment: That needs to be incorporated into the question itself, whatever. You can do that through the *edit* link beneath the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No "The top gets higher, the more that I climb." is correct.  It means as I make progress, the goal changes and is now farther away.

Comment: I thought the sentence should of of the form "the more something gets, the more I do something". It's the first time I see this form.

Comment: @whatever - That would mean something different.  For example, "The pig gets fatter the more that I feed it" is not the same as "The fatter the pig gets, the more I feed it."  The first one means "I feed the pig more, and as a result, it gets fatter."  The second one means "As the pig gets fatter, I keep feeding it more."  I realize that this is a difficult and subtle point for a new speaker of English!

Comment: So the song means "the more I climb the higher the top gets" written in an unconventional way.

Comment: @whatever - Yes, now you have it!